# 'Pool not running' problem about using pathos multiprocessing in a loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, pathos

When I try to do some parallel Computing in a loop,

```py
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
for i in range(10):
    pool = Pool(4)
    x = [0,1,2,3]
    y = [4,5,6,7]
    pool.map(add, x, y)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

it returns errors:

```
ValueError: Pool not running
```

The only way I can find is:

```py
for i in range(10):
    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.restart()
    x = [0,1,2,3]
    y = [4,5,6,7]
    pool.map(add, x, y)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I expected I can re-assign a new pool in each iteration, but it seemed not to work. What happened?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the `pathos` author.  In `pathos`, a `Pool` is a singleton, so when you close the pool... instantiating a new `Pool` actually just gives you the closed pool.  There is, however, `restart` and `clear`.  I think you probably are looking for `clear`.  So, after `join` add `clear()` -- then the instantiation of the new pool will be as you expect.

```
Python 3.7.16 (default, Dec  7 2022, 05:04:27) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pathos.pools as pp
>>> pool = pp.ProcessPool()
>>> pool.map(lambda x:x*x, range(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
>>> pool.close()
>>> pool.join()
>>> pool.clear()
>>> 
>>> pool = pp.ProcessPool()
>>> pool.map(lambda x:x*x, range(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
>>> pool.close()
>>> pool.join()
>>> pool.clear()
>>>
>>> # actually, this works too (after the clear)...
>>> pool.map(lambda x:x*x, range(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
>>>
```